# Why can't I use npm start to launch my react app anymore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm getting an error on all branches of my working website that is hosted on Heroku and running just fine. However when I try to launch it locally by using npm start I'm getting this error message in the terminal. I get the same thing in wsl and windows 10. Is there a problem with create-react-app?

Starting the development server...

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn powershell.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tippingpoint@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the tippingpoint@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/joshua/.npm/_logs/2020-09-06T22_57_45_967Z-debug.log
```

here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "tippingpoint",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.5",
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.9",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.13",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "graphql": "^14.3.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.4",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "offix-cache": "^0.15.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: seems like you updated it

Comment: @GetSet, forgive my ignorance. I'm still learning. Which thing did I update that gave me this error and how do I stop the error? Thanks

Comment: Please share your package.json for client/react

Comment: @sgrmhdk, I've edited that into my original question

Comment: I get the same error when I use nodemon or nodemon start @sandr